# How to delete Key Alias in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, certificate, alias, sign

I was testing app sign in android studio 4 and want to delete some test key alias from the list but there is no option.

Should I use some command or delete files?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could open the key store via some third party tools([Keystore explorer download](https://keystore-explorer.org/downloads.html)), and delete unwanted key.

To delete the Key alias previously selected, you just enter the box and press backspace.

[image]